# SKLabelNode Won't Update Text From Function

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit, swift5, sklabelnode

I have this game project and it has a coin system. I also have an option for users to watch a video ad to get 50 coins added to their total. Since the shop page is a SKScene, I run the ad through the view controller and when it is done presenting, the viewcontroller runs a function inside the scene that should update the amount of coins and the label that displays them.

Here is the code for my view controller:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController , GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {

var rewardBasedVideo: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!
var rewardvideoisinprogress = false
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

var adcounter = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    adcounter = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "AdCounter")
    print(adcounter)

    createandloadvideoad()

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3343126174384559/7308554354")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)

    ThemeShop().updatecoins()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.presentvideoad), name: NSNotification.Name("video"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.inter), name: NSNotification.Name("inter_"), object: nil)

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenu") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true 
    }
}

@objc func inter(){
    adcounter = adcounter + 1
    print(adcounter)
    if adcounter == 2{
        adcounter = 0
        if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            interstitial = createad()
        } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(adcounter, forKey: "AdCounter")  
}

func createad() -> GADInterstitial {
    let inter = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3343126174384559/7308554354`")

    inter.load(GADRequest())

    return inter
}

func createandloadvideoad(){
    rewardBasedVideo = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()
    rewardBasedVideo?.delegate = self
    if !rewardvideoisinprogress && rewardBasedVideo?.isReady == false{

        //ca-app-pub-3343126174384559/3425197396
        rewardBasedVideo?.load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
        rewardvideoisinprogress = true
    }
}

@objc func presentvideoad(){
    if rewardBasedVideo?.isReady == true{
        rewardBasedVideo?.present(fromRootViewController: self)

    }else{
        print("Was NOt Reardyadjfsjfsalfkj")

    }
    createandloadvideoad()
}

func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                        didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    print("Reward based video ad failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    rewardvideoisinprogress = false
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print("Reward based video ad is received.")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidOpen(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print("Opened reward based video ad.")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidStartPlaying(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print("Reward based video ad started playing.")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    rewardvideoisinprogress = false

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1500) , execute: {
        print("Brikdsajfaslkd")
        ThemeShop().updatecoins()
    })
}

func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                        didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    var coins = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Coins")
    coins = coins + 50
    UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")  
}
```

}

This is the function inside the SKScene:

```
func updatecoins(){
    print("Updating")
    coins = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Coins")
    print("Coins: \(coins)")

    self.coinlabel.text = String(self.coins)
    print(self.coinlabel.text)  
}
```

I know that the coins are being added to the balance behind the scenes because if I exit the scene and reenter, the coins show up like they should.

Comment: Dude, excessive white spaces are devil work! you should really clean that stuff up before posting it. It makes it way harder to read because you don't see as much on the screen, as well you need to figure out which code is relevant to the question and don't include code that's not

Comment: is MainMenu the same thing as ThemeShop? I don't see anywhere in that code where you instatiate a scene named ThemeShop

Comment: @RonMyschuk ThemeShop is a different scene that is loaded later

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to call a function on a class variable of ThemeShop you need to be calling the func on an instance variable of the class.

you don't show your ViewController code so you may have to adapt this accordingly

have a scene variable at the top of your viewController

```
private var themeShop: ThemeShop!
```

then in your viewDidLoad when you load the scene put it inside of the variable

```
//this is if you are loading your scene from an sks file. 
//your code may be different if it is just loaded from code with no sks file
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "ThemeShop") {
    self.themeShop = scene
```

then in your viewController when you need to access the scene

```
func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    rewardvideoisinprogress = false

    sleep(1)
    themeShop.updatecoins()  
}
```

Comment: There were a couple problems with this that Xcode forced me to fix(I won't go into them) but I keep getting hit with this error, "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: that could mean anything, you need to give details about where that error stops on when trying to run. You really should add the code in your question above for how you load your ThemeShop scene

Comment: I should clarify that error can't mean anything. you are probably trying to reference an instance variable incorrectly or that isn't instantiated yet

Comment: Ron's answer is almost certainly along the lines of what the problem is. You're calling updatecoins on ThemeShop(), which almost certainly is just making a new instance of a scene and then immediately throwing it away, i.e., doing nothing. After the video finishes and you update UserDefaults.standard, you need to call updatecoins for the existing scene that's being presented and that has the label node in question.  Don't call updatecoins for a new instance of that same scene.

Answer (score 0):

I think you label is not updating because you are not on the `main` queue. Also I made some changes to your code. You shouldn't use `sleep()` better use `asyncAfter`:

```
func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    isRewardVideoInProgress = false

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        ThemeShop().updatecoins()  
    }
}

func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                    didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    var coins = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Coins")
    coins = coins + 50
    UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")   
}

func updatecoins(){
    print("Updating")
    coins = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Coins")
    print("Coins: \(coins)")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.coinlabel.text = "\(self.coins)"
        print(self.coinlabel.text)  
    }
}
```

Comment: Nico, you can put the func call on whichever queue you want, it's never going to get through. ThemeShop() is a new instance of the scene not a reference to the one that is already open. this answer does not solve the problem.